# Tomcat and IntelliJ crossorigin configuration

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to call an API that I developed but I get this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I have done some research and I found two solutions:

1. Add the annotation `@CrossOrigin` to my API class but it doesn't work.
2. Configure tomcat server to be able to handle cross-origin issue. But I am using IntelliJ and the tomcat integrated with it. I can't find the configuration file.

Comment: The basic premise of these cross origin errors is that your browser isn't trusting a webpage that was retrieved from one host and port to make ajax requests to a different host or port. There are many ways to solve this problem, one is to change your browser settings if you only need it to work for you.

Comment: I need it to work not only for me